# Is hash-table still a good option for very specific time constratint application?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I was asked what data structure is good for GUARANTEED time constraint operations. The main features are lookup, insert and delete and we want to have guaranteed time, eg 0.000005msec, for each opeartion. Data is coming constantly.

Is hash-table(with re-sizing option when load factor is reached a threshold) a good option? I mean defining threshold based on the time constraint and then resize/rehash table when that threshold is reached.

Thanks

Comment: I don think hash-tables would be a good option, since collisions can occur

Comment: The best lookup structure is going to depend a lot on your data. What is the nature of the keys? Integer? String? Something else? What is the percentage of each operation? That is, of 10,000 total operations, what percentage is lookup, what percentage is insert, and what percentage is delete? How large is this hash table expected to get?

Comment: The interviewer emphesized on the specific time constraint (T) and he asked me whether O(1) lookup of hashtable is equivalant to guaranted time? If not, what data structure? Then he followed up with insert and delete. I thought we could relate load factor and the T value to mak sure about that. So, @JimMischel how do you proceed the argument for each data type?

Comment: It really depends on how deep the interviewer wanted you to go. In broad terms, a hash table gives you O(1) insert, delete, and lookup. But there's a big difference between O(1) and a definite time guarantee. Having to re-hash when you want to extend the table is going to kill your O(1) guarantee. Unlucky hashing can cause some buckets to become over full, etc. There are whole *books* on the topic of fast lookup in large data sets. The nature of the keys matters because if the keys have a limited range, you could potentially directly index an array.

Comment: What about bloom filter? It gives us guaranted time (in the worst case we need to access the disk to make sure the key ACTUALLY exists. But of course we can not support delete.

Comment: Bloom filter can tell you if something actually exists. Is that all you want? Just an existence check? Plus, Bloom filter comes with a probability of false positives. You might say something exists when it really doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hash Table is the best option you have got for lookup since it can give you a search time of O(1). For insertion and deletion you will have to consider the cases for collision where you will either need to rehash the table as you specified or follow one of the collision handling techniques e.g. linear probing, quaddatic probing etc. But as the data is coming constantly you will have to resize the table more frequently.